# For Firebase Dynamic Linking, what do you enter for Team ID if you are using an IOS wildcard?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

Where can I find the Team ID for IOS to enter into Firebase for Dynamic linking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the team Id from developer account. Log in to the developer account, go to the account details there you will find the Team Id.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  On Apple Dev >  provision section , it just shows that it's a Wild IOS * with no actual team ID.  Any idea what I would use for Firebase?  It's a required field for Dynamic links.

Comment: you have to go to account details. not in provisioning section. the top right where you see the the name of logged in user. click that and goto account detail

Comment: Thank You!  That was it, I found it in my account details.

Comment: Done (I think).  Thanks again for your help.  Cheers.